# Has anyone successfully compiled pcl_ros in Raspberry Pi boards?

Tags: ros-galactic, pcl

Could someone confirm if the package pcl_ros is compatible with ARM boards? I have attempted to compile it on a Raspberry Pi board using the options `--parallel-workers 1` or `--executor sequential`, but the board freezes when it reaches 83%.

If anyone has successfully compiled this package on an ARM board, please let me know. Your success would motivate me to continue searching for solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely works on arm boards, but pcl is a highly templated library and has a moderately large memory requirement when compiling against it. It's most likely that you're running out of memory.

I would strongly recommend against allowing parallel workers on a memory limited platform like the raspberry Pi. In addition adding a swap space on disk (preferably as high speed as possible SD cards can be very slow compared to memory) will keep you going. And you're likely to need to be quite patient.

You should be able to monitor your memory usage as it builds to make sure it doesn't run out. If it does crash check for OOM messages in your syslog.

Comment: thank you for the insight, how about cross compiling? do you think it will work?

Comment: I expect that you can cross compile it without any more challenge than general cross compiling.